# sqlite prepopulation

Tags: sqlite

How to prepopulate an sqlite database at development time? I found a tutorial how to use a prepopulated sqlite with android but I want to populate the database with data from a text file. Is it possible to write a java program that will read the data from a text file insert into sqlite database and save the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you described is what you need to do:

1. Read data from a text file
2. Generate "insert" sentences from it
3. Run them against your SQLite database

Done. Your DB is now pre-populated.

Make sure you flag this "pre population:" command so you don't run it twice.

Comment: But how to run them against SQLite database without creating an android project?

Comment: There are a lot of libraries for connecting a NON-ANDROID Java (or any other languages for that matter) project to a SQLite database.

Comment: Or, you can run it within your ANDROID application. The first time it runs.